# callback function is having issue with void expression in C?

Tags: c, pointers, callback

I am learning the basics of Function pointer in C and their calls backs. But I am stuck due to line 15. The source won't compile. Compiler says

In function ‘main’:
error: invalid use of void expression @
`call_fun(displayMessage(Message))`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void displayMessage( void * string){
printf("%s\n", (char*)string);
}

//function pointer as argument
void call_fun (void (*funPtr)()) {
displayMessage(); // call Back function that funPtr points out to 
}

int main(){
char * Message = " Hello World";
call_fun(displayMessage(Message));
return 0;
}
```

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1):

This ...

```
void (*funPtr)()
```

... declares `funPtr` as a pointer to a non-variadic function accepting an unspecified number of arguments of unspecified type, and returning `void`.

This ...

```
displayMessage(Message)
```

... is a function *call*, whose type, in your case, is `void`.  The types `void` and `void (*funPtr)()` are not compatible.

Presumably, you want to pass *a pointer to* `displayMessage` instead of *the result of calling* `displayMessage`.  For the former, just use the function name:

```
call_fun(displayMessage);
```

But you will quickly notice that the message itself does not appear in that expression, and this is a problem if you want the code that calls `call_fun` to specify the message to pass to `displayMessage`.  To enable that, you would need to pass the message as a separate parameter, or come up with some other means to convey it to `call_func`.<sup>*</sup>

You should consider also function `call_fun()`.  You should recognize that it declares parameter `funPtr` but never references it.  You should also recognize that it explicitly calls `displayMessage()` (with the wrong number of parameters), which doesn't make sense if its caller is supposed to be the one specifying what function to call.  Additionally, although it is allowed to declare a function pointer that does not provide a prototype, it is almost always better for function pointers to be declared with prototypes.

Overall, then:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void displayMessage(const char *string) {
    printf("%s\n", string);
}

//function pointer as argument
void call_fun (void (*funPtr)(const char *), const char *message) {
    funPtr(message); // call the function that funPtr points out to 
}

int main(void) {
    const char *Message = "Hello World";
    call_fun(displayMessage, Message);
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup> However, a more typical callback scenario is for one component to specify the (callback) function to a different component that chooses the timing of and arguments to the calls.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification, sir. I've one more question on the code that you have written 
'void call_fun (void (*funPtr)(const char *), const char *message) '
I couldn't get the use of the the first argument which is 'const char *' , 

In main , that argument has been replaced by displayMessage which is a void type function  but declaration is of const char *

Comment: @EnslavedMortal, my revised version of function `call_fun` accepts exactly two arguments -- the first a function pointer, and the second a `const char *`.  The call in `main` correctly matches those.  I think you're asking about the first appearance of `const char *` in the declaration. That is not an argument to `call_fun`; rather, it is part of the type of parameter `funPtr`.  That type includes a prototype for the pointed-to function, as I discussed, declaring that it accepts one argument of type `const char *`.

Comment: Thanks again. I got the gist of it now. 
:)